# DES Encryption and decryption algorithm in swift

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, des

I am trying to use DES algorithm for Encryption and decryption in swift

But with the code that I have written the encrypted message is changing for every build

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CommonCrypto

public class IAppEncryptionUtitlity: NSObject {
    private override init(){}
    public static let sharedNetworkVar: IAppEncryptionUtitlity = IAppEncryptionUtitlity()
    let key = IAppConfig.key
     func myEncrypt(encryptData:String) -> NSData?{

        var myKeyData : NSData = ("DyfmgL9p" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSData
        var myRawData : NSData = encryptData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
        var iv : [UInt8] = [56, 101, 63, 23, 96, 182, 209, 205]  // I didn't use
        var buffer_size : size_t = myRawData.length + kCCBlockSize3DES
        var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.allocate(capacity: buffer_size)
        var num_bytes_encrypted : size_t = 0

        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
        let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)

        var Crypto_status: CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, myKeyData.bytes, keyLength, nil, myRawData.bytes, myRawData.length, buffer, buffer_size, &num_bytes_encrypted)

        if UInt32(Crypto_status) == UInt32(kCCSuccess){

            var myResult: NSData = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: num_bytes_encrypted)

            free(buffer)
            print("my result \(myResult)") //This just prints the data

            let keyData: NSData = myResult

            let hexString = keyData.hexEncodedString()
            print("hex result \(keyData)") // I needed a hex string output


            //myDecrypt(decryptData: myResult) // sent straight to the decryption function to test the data output is the same
            return myResult
        }else{
            free(buffer)
            return nil
        }
    }
    func myDecrypt(decryptData : NSData) -> NSData?{

        var mydata_len : Int = decryptData.length
        var keyData : NSData = ("myEncryptionKey" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSData

        var buffer_size : size_t = mydata_len+kCCBlockSizeAES128
        var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.allocate(capacity: buffer_size)
        var num_bytes_encrypted : size_t = 0

        var iv : [UInt8] = [56, 101, 63, 23, 96, 182, 209, 205]  // I didn't use

        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
        let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)

        var decrypt_status : CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, keyData.bytes, keyLength, nil, decryptData.bytes, mydata_len, buffer, buffer_size, &num_bytes_encrypted)

        if UInt32(decrypt_status) == UInt32(kCCSuccess){

            var myResult : NSData = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: num_bytes_encrypted)
            free(buffer)
            print("decrypt \(myResult)")

            var stringResult = NSString(data: myResult as Data, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("my decrypt string \(stringResult!)")
            return myResult
        }else{
            free(buffer)
            return nil

        }
    }
}
extension NSData {
    struct HexEncodingOptions: OptionSet {
        let rawValue: Int
        static let upperCase = HexEncodingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    }

    func hexEncodedString(options: HexEncodingOptions = []) -> String {
        let format = options.contains(.upperCase) ? "%02hhX" : "%02hhx"
        //var map = { String(format: format, $0) }.joined()

        return ""
    }
}
```

Output is changing for every build . Whats wrong in the code or

And is kCCOptionPKCS7Padding and kCCOptionPKCS5Padding is same?

Thanks In advance

Comment: Unfortunately as somebody that tried out Swift just once (although this is more ObjectiveC rather than Swift I guess), I don't immediately see the error. however, as for your last question about the padding, [that I can answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172).

Comment: You should give some input and output so that some can test.

Comment: You should also justify why you're using DES in 2019...

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark As it was already implemented in .net and android long back now the same functionality is implementing in iOS so no other option other than DES

Comment: Well, you do have many other options - like changing the .NET and Android to use AES.  Are you aware that a DES key can be broken in a matter of hours on a standard laptop?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I am not aware of it.

Comment: Then you should read about how DES was broken years ago.  You might as well not bother encrypting anything if you're going to use DES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got Solution by changing the code

```
import UIKit
import CommonCrypto
var message: String?

public class IAppEncryptionUtitlity: NSObject {

   //Calling method to encrypt using extensions
    public func methodToCallEncryption( stringToEncrypt : String ) ->String {
        let iVValue:String = "nzug8FrX"
        let keyValue = IAppConfig.key //DyfmgL9p
        let encoded = stringToEncrypt.desEncrypt( key : keyValue , iv : iVValue )
        return encoded!
    }

    public func methodToCallDecryption( stringToDecrypt : String ) -> String{
        let iVValue:String = "nzug8FrX"
        let keyValue = IAppConfig.key //DyfmgL9p
        let decoded = stringToDecrypt.desEncrypt( key : keyValue , iv : iVValue )
        return decoded!
    }
}
extension String {

    func desEncrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
        if let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.count)) + kCCBlockSizeDES) {


            let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeDES)
            let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
            let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmDES)
            let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)



            var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

            let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                      algoritm,
                                      options,
                                      (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                                      iv,
                                      (data as NSData).bytes, data.count,
                                      cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted)

            if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
                cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
                let base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
                return base64cryptString

            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func desDecrypt(key:String, iv:String, options:Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
        if let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let data = NSData(base64Encoded: self, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters),
            let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.length)) + kCCBlockSizeDES) {

            let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeDES)
            let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
            let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmDES)
            let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(options)

            var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

            let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                      algoritm,
                                      options,
                                      (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                                      iv,
                                      data.bytes, data.length,
                                      cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted)

            if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
                cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
                let unencryptedMessage = String(data: cryptData as Data, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
                return unencryptedMessage
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 3):

We can use a String category like shown below for all symmetric encryption and decryption including DES, 3DES, and AES.

```
/// Extension for Symmetric Encryption and Decryption with DES, 3DES, AES algorithms
extension String {
    
    /// Encrypts message with DES algorithm
    func desEncrypt(key:String) -> String? {
        
        return symetricEncrypt(key: key, blockSize: kCCBlockSizeDES, keyLength: size_t(kCCKeySizeDES), algorithm: UInt32(kCCAlgorithmDES))
    }
    
    /// Encrypts message with 3DES algorithm
    func tripleDesEncrypt(key:String) -> String? {
        
        return symetricEncrypt(key: key, blockSize: kCCBlockSize3DES, keyLength: size_t(kCCKeySize3DES), algorithm: UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES))
    }
    
    /// Encrypts message with AES 128 algorithm
    func aes128Encrypt(key:String) -> String? {
        
        return symetricEncrypt(key: key, blockSize: kCCBlockSizeAES128, keyLength: size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128), algorithm: UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128))
    }
    
    /// Encrypts message with AES algorithm
    func aesEncrypt(key:String) -> String? {
        
        return symetricEncrypt(key: key, blockSize: kCCBlockSizeAES128, keyLength: size_t(kCCKeySizeAES256), algorithm: UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES))
    }
    
    /// Encrypts a message with symmetric algorithm
    func symetricEncrypt(key:String, blockSize: Int, keyLength: size_t, algorithm: CCAlgorithm, options: Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
        let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
        let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
        
        let cryptData = NSMutableData(length: Int(data.length) + blockSize)!

        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)

        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                  algorithm,
                                  UInt32(options),
                                  keyData.bytes, keyLength,
                                  nil,
                                  data.bytes, data.length,
                                  cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                  &numBytesEncrypted)
        
        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
            let base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
            return base64cryptString
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    /// Decrypts message with DES algorithm
    func desDecrypt(key:String) -> String? {
        
        return symetricDecrypt(key: key, blockSize: kCCBlockSizeDES, keyLength: size_t(kCCKeySizeDES), algorithm: UInt32(kCCAlgorithmDES))
    }
    
    /// Decrypts message with 3DES algorithm
    func tripleDesDecrypt(key:String) -> String? {
        
        return symetricDecrypt(key: key, blockSize: kCCBlockSize3DES, keyLength: size_t(kCCKeySize3DES), algorithm: UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES))
    }
    
    /// Decrypts message with AES 128 algorithm
    func aes128Decrypt(key:String) -> String? {
        
        return symetricDecrypt(key: key, blockSize: kCCBlockSizeAES128, keyLength: size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128), algorithm: UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128))
    }
    
    /// Decrypts message with AES algorithm
    func aesDecrypt(key:String) -> String? {
        
        return symetricDecrypt(key: key, blockSize: kCCBlockSizeAES128, keyLength: size_t(kCCKeySizeAES256), algorithm: UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES))
    }

    /// Decrypts a message with symmetric algorithm
    func symetricDecrypt(key:String, blockSize: Int, keyLength: size_t, algorithm: CCAlgorithm, options: Int = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding) -> String? {
        if let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let data = NSData(base64Encoded: self, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters),
            let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int((data.length)) + blockSize) {

            let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
            var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

            let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                      algorithm,
                                      UInt32(options),
                                      (keyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength,
                                      nil,
                                      data.bytes, data.length,
                                      cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted)

            if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
                cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
                let unencryptedMessage = String(data: cryptData as Data, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
                return unencryptedMessage
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Full source:
https://gist.github.com/tharindu/1cf0201492e41f1c287e51abb02902cd